# Generation IDs Strategy Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 and I have a temporal table where I store data from a Excel file. The question is that I need that each time I store information in this table the fist id is one. The AUTO strategy of Doctrine doesn't permit that, exist any strategy for that.
Thanks and sorry my english, is very bad

Comment: Since your table is temporary you can just drop it and create it again. Or you can truncate it.

Comment: or set yourself the id value doing `object->setId($counter);`